# Imagem se expandindo pela minha div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Olá, estou iniciando em CSS, e resolvi criar este layout, porem depois de definido meu flexbox minha imagem central (dado) esta ocupando todo o espaço da div, como se houvesse outra imagem por trás , de primeira pensei que fosse pelo ::after mas mesmo removendo ele o problema persiste.
(O layout correto (Hyperlink) deveria ser apenas 1 dado)

```css
:root {
    font-size: 30px;
}
body {
    background-image: url(img/waves.svg);
    background-color: #0c794f;
    background-size: cover;
}

/* Modal Styles */
#game-modal {
    background: rgb(214,214,214);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(214,214,214,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    width: 750px;
    height: 450px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
                0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
                0 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
                0 16px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

}

.player-name, .action-btn, #dice-title  {
    font-family: 'Junar', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.points,.current-score,#sub-title {
    font-family: 'Poetsen One', sans-serif;
}

.fa-arrow-alt-circle-right {color: red;}

/*  Game Title  */
#dice-title {
    font-size:  50px; 
    color: red;
    margin: 15px auto;

}

#sub-title {
    font-size: 1rem ;
    color: #0c794f;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 0.7;
   
   
}

.points {
    font-size: 100px;
    color: #0c794f;
    
}

.current-score {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #919191;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.12),
                0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12),
                0 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.12),
                0 8px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}


/* Buttons */
.action-btn {
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#btn-roll:hover {
    background-color: #0c794f;
}
#btn-roll:hover i{
    animation: spin 1s infinite;
}
#btn-roll:focus {
    background-color: #bd0000;
}

#btn-hold:hover {
    background-color: #0c794f;
}

#btn-hold:hover i {
    font-size: 20px;
}

#btn-hold:focus {
    background-color: #bd0000;
}

i {transition: font-size 0.3s;}

@keyframes spin {
    to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

#dice {
    background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/wXCVpeI.png");
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px ;
    background-size:150px 150px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: -1px 15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
            inset 1px -10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

/*  Shadown Effect - Dice  */
#dice::after {
    content: "";
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;    
    filter: blur(15px);
    opacity: 0.5;
    height: 40%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotateX(-100deg);
    bottom: -20%;
    z-index: -1;  
}

/* Postions */

#board {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.fa-plus-circle {font-size: 15px;}

.player-name {
    font-size:25px;
}

#player-1 {   
    flex: 1 6 30%;
    order: 1;
}
#dice {
    flex: 3 1 40%;
    order: 2;
}
#player-2 {
    flex: 1 6 30%;
    order: 3;
}

#btn-hold {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 5px 60px;

}

#btn-roll {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 5px 36px;

}

#titulo , #control-buttons {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='CSS/dice-game.css' >
    
        <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='CSS/fontawesome-free-5.11.2-web/css/all.css'>
       
        <title>Dice - The Game</title>
    </head>
    <body>      
        <main id='game-modal'>

            <header id="titulo">
                <h1 id='dice-title'><i class="fa fa-dice"></i> Dice
                <span id='sub-title'>The Game</span>
                </h1>
            </header>
            <section id='board'>
                <!-- TOPO (Titulo do jogo)-->
            
                 
                <!-- JOGADOR 1 -->
                <div class='player' id="player-1">
                    <span class='player-name'><i class="fa fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Player 1 </span>  
                    <span class="points">200</span>
                    <!-- TOTAL DE PONTOS ATUAIS -->            
                    <div class='current-score'>Total: <span class='score' id='score-player-1'>20 Points </span></div>
                </div>
                
                <!-- DADO -->
                <div id='dice'></div>    
                
                <!-- JOGADOR 2 -->
                <div class='player'id="player-2">
                    <span class='player-name'><i class="fa fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Player 2 </span>
                    <span class="points">100</span>
                    <!-- TOTAL DE PONTOS ATUAIS -->
                    <div class='current-score'>Total: <span class='score' id='score-player-2'>50 Points</span></div>
                </div>

                
            </section>

            <!-- BOTÕES DE AÇÃO (Rolar ou segurar)-->
            <div id='control-buttons'>         
                <button class='action-btn' id='btn-roll'><i class="fa fa-sync-alt"></i> Roll dice </button>
                <button class='action-btn' id='btn-hold'><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Save </button>
            </div>

        </main>
        <script src='Js/the-pig-game.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eu não entendi qual o problema, eu executei o código e parece normal. Poderia apontar onde está o problema?

Comment: Esta vendo que aparece 2 dados ? pois é era para aparecer só um kkk

Comment: Agora eu entendi... votando para reabrir a pergunta.

Comment: acho mais pratica refazer essa pergunta mesmo, infelizmente